# set path in vagrant machine

Tags: shell, path, vagrant

I have a file `export.sh` which has this content:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/opt/hadoop/jdk1.7.0_51"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I have another shell script (`setup.sh`) in which I am sourcing `export.sh`:

```
source /vagrant/export.sh
```

`setup.sh` is called during provisioning:

```
master.vm.provision :shell, path: "scripts/setup.sh"
```

But when the machine boots and I try (for example):

```
which java
```

it shows blank...

How can I include the newly added path exports in Vagrant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line to your `setup.sh` file:

```
echo "source /vagrant/scripts/export.sh" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
```

This will ensure that the exports are loaded each time you ssh into the machine, which is what you want to do.

This assumes that your `setup.sh` is located in the `/vagrant/scripts` directory on your virtual machine.

Comment: Let me try this once.

Comment: No luck

vagrant@precise32:~$ echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin
vagrant@precise32:~$ cat .bashrc | grep source
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
source /vagrant/scripts/export.sh
vagrant@precise32:~$ cat /vagrant/scripts/export.sh
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/hadoop/jdk1.7.0_51
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
vagrant@precise32:~$

Comment: [This Vagrantfile](https://raw.github.com/Turistforeningen/hytteadmin/master/Vagrantfile) is how I do exports for my virtual machines.

Comment: @HansKristian your link is not valid anymore.